# Long-term visa expiration + Count towards Schengen tourist days?

Tags: visas, schengen, poland, 90-180-visa-rules, transition-of-visa-status

I am an American citizen living in Poland for 6 months.

I arrived in Poland on February 1, 2016 without a Visa.
The count toward my Schengen days began.
I received my Work Visa for Poland on April 7, 2016.  The work visa expires on July 7th.
I intend to stay in Poland until July 30, 2016 (which is 180 days after I entered on February 1)

My question is, do the days that I am on a Work Visa count toward my "90 days within a 180 day period" as a tourist?  And when my work visa expires on July 7th, will I be able to remain in Poland until July 30?

February 1 -> April 7 = 66 days
July 7 -> July 30 = 23 days
Total days as a tourist = 89 days

Answer (score 4):

You should be fine.  Article 6, paragraph 2 of the [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32016R0399) says:

> For the purposes of implementing paragraph 1, the date of entry shall be considered as the first day of stay on the territory of the Member States and the date of exit shall be considered as the last day of stay on the territory of the Member States. **Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States.**

(Emphasis added.)

In fact, you can stay a few more days, because you've made a couple of mistakes in your calculation.  First, since 7 April and 7 July appear to be covered by your work visa, you should not count them in your 90/180 calculation.  Second, days are counted inclusively.  So your first chunk of days is 66 days from 1 February through *6* April, inclusive.  Your second chunk of days is from 8 July through 30 July, inclusive, for a total of 23 days.

But on 30 July, you have only *88* days of presence, because the 180-day period that ends on 30 July starts on *2* February.  You therefore hit 90 days on 2 October, so you have to leave the Schengen area before midnight on that date.

This assumes that you don't set foot in any Schengen country other than Poland during the period 7 April through 7 July.  If you do, you'll have to reconsider the calculation.  If you spend enough days outside Poland, in fact, you might need to leave as soon as your work visa expires.

Comment: Phoog, thanks for referencing the Schengen Borders Code.  This answers my question perfectly.

Comment: "2 October" is a typo, right?

Comment: @o.m. no, it's not. Did I miscalculate?

Comment: @phoog, I think I see my mistake. From August, days in February fall out of the 180 days period, I forgot that.

Comment: @o.m. exactly. But just a few days in Germany near the end of the work visa would change that and require the traveller to leave on the expiration date of the work permit.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that I have a Multiple-Entry Type D Visa.  So, I can remain in the Schengen zone after July 7th, until July 30, because the days when I was under the Visa were not tallied toward my total 90/180.