# Can you leave the country for more than 90 days on a Germany Youth Mobility Visa? If not, does any other Schengen country's visa let you do that?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas

I read somewhere that you can only travel 90/180 days from a few years back, but I wonder if that's still the case, and if it's enforced given open border.

Comment: Travel to where? Other Schengen countries? If so, then yes that is still the limit. How they enforce it given free movement across signatory states? I do not know.

Comment: Are you asking if the validity of a Youth Mobility Visa is affected if you travel outside Germany for extended periods, or are you asking how the 90/180 day rule works for those with a residence permit/long stay visa https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67988/long-term-visa-expiration-count-towards-schengen-tourist-days?

Comment: I'm asking if I can leave Germany for more than 90/180 days with a YMV?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can leave Germany for as long as you want with a youth mobility visa.  However, you cannot spend more than 90 days in any 180-day period in other Schengen countries with that visa.  You could exceed that limit in another Schengen country if you had another D visa from that country.  Similarly, if you go to a non-Schengen country such as Canada or the UK, you can stay there for as long as that country will allow you.