# British Citizen working in Greece

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas, greece

As a British citizen obtaining a work permit for Greece for the summer months I would like to know if the days i am permitted to work are definitely not included in my 90/180 days. I would also then like to know if once i finish working and my contract terminates if i can just stay in Greece on my tourist 90 day visa without having to leave a re-enter the country.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Long-term visa expiration + Count towards Schengen tourist days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67988/long-term-visa-expiration-count-towards-schengen-tourist-days)

Answer (score 2):

This EU site [Greece - Employed worker](https://immigration-portal.ec.europa.eu/greece-employed-worker_en) states:

> To work in Greece as an employed worker, you need: **a national visa for employment**.

In the form of a visa (in your passport) it is clear that the **type D** visa exempts you from the 90 day rule while in Greece.

The 90 days starts again after the date that the visa expires.

From a question, either on this site or Expatriates, it was stated by the user that Sweden does not issue a visa for a period up to 3 months, so it is not always clear (from what is contained in your passport) that you were exempt and you must therefore retain the given paper work permit as proof.