# Does time in the Schengen Area on a residence permit count toward the 90 day maximum?

Tags: schengen, europe, 90-180-visa-rules, residence-permits

Here's a scenario:

- Say I am in a country in the Schengen Area on a residence permit that expires Jan 1, and have been here for a few years continuously
- I leave the country to go live somewhere else outside of the Schengen Area on Jan 1
- On Jan 15 I want to come back to visit this same country for a week

When does the 180 day window start for me? In particular, can I come back on Jan 15 in this scenario without violating the rule or does the window lookback 180 days flat to even when I had a valid residence permit? That would seem odd to me, but I can't find any language explicitly allowing this. maybe because it is a somewhat rare case.

Comment: Exchange students do it fairly often, often without leaving.

Comment: The days as a resident, while in the country of residence, does not count for the **90 days** of a 180 day period. Therefore a return on the 15th would be day 1 of 90.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Regarding your edits: does the type of permit matter? I am on a EU blue card talent passport, which I guess is a sort of residence permit though I've always just called it (maybe wrongly) a visa.

Comment: A **national visa**, type D, (which also does not count for the 90 days) can only be valid up to a year. The **type** of resident permit is not important.

Comment: @MarkJohnson So indeed my Talent Passport Blue Card works here and as you note above, my first day back after expiry is day 1 of 90, correct (just getting hung up a bit on visa vs. residence permit since I've never thought about the distinction but it seems I should be fine here). Info here on this visa for France: https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16922?lang=en

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Long-term visa expiration + Count towards Schengen tourist days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67988/long-term-visa-expiration-count-towards-schengen-tourist-days)